# Storing numbers larger than Big integer C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, primes, biginteger

I am having a really hard time finding a way to store massive prime numbers in c#. I tried everything but nothing worked out for me. For example. How can I store this number.

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

---

Do you know how or what an external library that could store that?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Store?  Or apply math operations on?

Comment: does this not fit in c# BigInteger? docs say that its effectively unlimited in size https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0

Comment: Is the issue that the number is in hexadecimal, not the fact that it's huge?

Comment: That number fits just fine in a BigInteger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of an integer representable by `BigInteger` is effectively only constrained by the maximum addressable memory of the program if not the computer itself. You can parse one by using `BigInteger.Parse` or `BigInteger.TryParse` and passing `NumberStyles.HexNumber` (minus the "0x" part of the string).

A note about `Parse`, if the first digit is "8" or higher, that will result in the first bit of the number's binary representation being a 1. Signed integers interpret this as being a negative number, so your resulting number will not only be a negative number, but it will be very different than the equivalent positive number's binary representation. To avoid this, prepend a "0" to the input string.

You can "store" it by either converting it back into a string with `ToString` or by converting it into a byte array with `ToByteArray`, appropriately enough.

```cs
var input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
var hugeNumber = BigInteger.Parse(input, NumberStyles.HexNumber);

var hugeNumberString = hugeNumber.ToString();
var hugeNumberBytes = hugeNumber.ToByteArray();

// You can reload the byte array by simply passing it to the `BigInteger` constructor.
var hugeNumberReconstructed = new BigInteger(hugeNumberBytes);
```

Comment: Related GitHub issue: [BigInteger incorrectly parses large integer hex string](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/50385): *“Closing this as "by design". [...] This is a long time difference and changing it will be breaking.”* The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.parse) are still not mentioning this quirk though.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias True, however prepending "0" to address the negative number problem also seems to fix that issue.

Comment: Sure, it's an easy fix if you are aware about this quirk. Otherwise it's a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger does it

```
var bytes = new List<Byte>();
string num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
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i+=2) {
    var b = num.Substring(i, 2);
    var x = Convert.ToByte(b, 16);
    bytes.Add(x);

}
var bn = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(bytes.ToArray());
```

debugger shows

```
bn  {-1570566720338582667927906308486331020678313192057614971584760731901058647139518057241123644094401330702204896434749395740948521204256830813802793411121615133171266951981018749121361010262657119536344690188227760522346385933065780960593402202465448470021036386883323238183599243975089536777184470963161425724987363228043371573877576452029605409494617533656095430483815839481907153364288401182596736380740919039955960610857082518546213313320880567980770439331102549009223218208548749082963734827189358268113429507100272583973032847664061854471533479116667574516065732839447648992011110538140617869829020597826272370250406178983259310517449686885092778023735816105275313156168057770834629675841435934157964159733407369373150569643832403368714414248477830355864648343905813412169307812679570071021264327268776159178258126189105355201727008666110957901070869422442964928204432497893639569923030486663520936478372141324725647779388824026436194349030123028127183590807988699910718883036274092296195738801238932240607706512065663168315105279062647762457541689320199801400963441351542207060400661407720411212987665329161135568453084989958577002926963319659401211071077577114413531153489686602746402174695962726389204418249748806498154334309175313426956505725867430885326612261827698634725487008721538567095488663671271012738141457858408427283049274115742675742516750037999118278841924003978633759158117873692177310838874149259276441739874499926101302480541938686564170604159164760763295532542904951250793468087996706862009509879288767160917718363858884333087557922625562601699376322568867851374429539180956730361131113520484694955462251349689481650791574910892992752905760719949241290478195310550499570804467728132132006347697735259131798874824194406553202473938274024972466003838104776740077783578318451208991087791302742074840248125227009}
```

Comment: Or use `BigInteger.Parse(num, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)` but make sure to make the first digit a 0.

Comment: @juharr dang - i only looked at constructors, life would have been simpler.

Answer (score 1):

BigInteger, but you need to add a Zero at the begining of the hexadecimal string number, to avoid get a negative number

```
public Class1()
    {
        var cadNumber =
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
        decimal.TryParse(
            cadNumber
            ,out decimal numberDecimal);
        var numberBigInteger = BigInteger.Parse(cadNumber, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        var numberLong = long.Parse(cadNumber, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

    }
```